# Missing symbols in Evince

Tags: xubuntu, fonts, pdf, evince

I'm having a problem where some symbols (usually µ) aren't being displayed in Evince, but come through fine in Ghostview.

[image]
<sup>**Screenshot comparison**</sup>

The PDFs are usually datasheets, so "You should have embedded the fonts" is not a helpful answer.  For example: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa197.pdf [edited].

I'm running Xubuntu 16.04, and recently had problems getting `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` to install correctly; I wound up pulling it straight from Debian and installing it using `dpkg` instead.

```
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

Comment: Where do you see a problem with the tps2660.pdf?  I'm running 16.04, did the Debian pull for the ttf-mscorefonts-installer, and don't see a problem in your documents's section 7.3, which includes the micro symbol.  Both evince and Firefox display correctly.

Comment: @ubfan1 - In section 7.3, Figure 43 at the bottom page 20, I can see the µ in the graph legend, and can confirm that's all characters rather than just embedded graphics.  I _cannot_ see them in sections 6.7-6.8, pages 7-10, where they appear in the units column.

Comment: @ubfan1 - Strike that, apparently I'm so tired of this problem that I'm getting my links wrong.  In http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps2660.pdf, the micros in section 7.3 are _not_ appearing on my Evince.  My earlier comments, and the screenshots, were from http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa197.pdf which I've changed the above to reflect.

Comment: @Rgaddi Are you still having this problem?